# Dipoles and determining molecular (a)symmetry

Tags: molecular-structure, dipole

What is a dipole? Also, how do you know if a molecule is symmetrical or asymmetrical?

For example, are the following symmetrical or asymmetrical? Can you tell just from the molecular formula? Which ones have dipoles?

- $\ce{O2}$
- $\ce{H2O}$
- $\ce{CO2}$

Are these concepts related?

Comment: Take a look at something like http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Quantum_Mechanics/Atomic_Theory/Intermolecular_Forces/Dipole-Dipole_Interactions, please and then edit your question to address the concepts that you still don't understand.

Comment: I'm nominating to reopen so it can be closed again as a duplicate of https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/1107/194.

Answer (score 1):

You should easily find the answers by searching the web.

A dipole is the separation of a positive charge and a negative charge in a molecule. Any 2 different atoms bonded together will have a dipole since their electronegativities are different.

A symmetrical molecule will either have a mirror plane or a rotation that will superimpose the atoms. Benzene has both a mirror plane and a rotation of 60°.

An asymmetrical molecule does not have a mirror plane or rotation. Ethanol is an example.